# Multi Level import in Python not working with Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

My file structure look like this

```
Module
|
|--Common
|       |
|       utils.py
|       credentials.ini
|-- Folder2
|--Folder3
|--Folder4
         | 
         Folder5
               |
               comp.py
```

I need to import `utils.py` functions in the `comp.py` file, but the problem is that utils itself needs the credentials.ini file for it to work.

I solved the problem in `utils.py` by giving it a absolute path like this `path=join(dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'credentials.ini')`
and in comp.py file I added this path to env using

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../")
```

While this worked when I ran comp.py but I need to schedule it on airflow for it to run. Whenever airflow schedules `comp.py` to run it can't find the `utils.py` (Airflow and the module package are in different paths). Any idea how I can resolve it? I don't want to manually add the `utils.py` path to the env.

P.S The whole directly is initialized as a package. I have added `__init__.py` to the main module folder as well as all the subdirectories in it.

EDIT: Fixed Formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow loads DAGs in a sandboxed environment and it does not handle all the various ways importing works when you run Python file as script. This is due to security and the way how different components of the distributed system work.

See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html but more detailed information  especially the "development" versoin of the documentation that will be released in 2.2 (especially the "best practices"):

http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/modules_management.html#best-practices-for-module-loading

There are some best practices to follow:

1. Place all your python files in one of the modules that are already on pythonpath
2. Always use absolute imports, do not use "relative" references
3. Don't rely on your current working directory setting (likely this is what your problem was really - your current working directory was different than you expected).

In your case what will likely work is:

- write a method in your 'utils.py" - for example "get_credentials_folder()".
- in this method use `__file__` to derive the path of the "utils.py" and find the absolute path of the expected folder containing it (use `pardir` and `abspath`)
- add that absolute path you get to the sys.path

Comment: Thanks! this worked though I had to manually append the path in my script, airflow didn't detect my PYTHONPATH even after I had exported in bashrc

Comment: Ah yeah . Depending how you run  Airflow , PYTHONPATH from bashrc might not be used - usually you run Airflow as a different user and using some upstart or smth and then you need to set `PYTHONPATH` in a different place.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by upstart? I am new to airflow if that's not apparent ;)

Comment: Whatever is the way you run airflow :) 'upstart' is one of the generic ways how you can start services automatically - this was just an example, nothing specific to Airflow.